# Conditional htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to make a conditional redirect using .htaccess in a way that if somebody access my domain directly (example.com) he will be redirected to a subdomain (subdomain.example.com) or may be to another domain, but if someone accesses it through a particular URL  (example.com/magic) he get's redirected to example.com i.e. main domain.

In other words, I wanted my users to access the main domain (example.com) only if they are using example.com/magic.
My htaccess is presently redirecting all users of main domain to a subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/sub\.example\.com" [R=301, L]
```

I couldn't find though, how to put the condition in my htaccess.

Comment: So anything other that `/magic` should be redirected to subdomain?

Comment: yes, to a subdomain (or maybe to another domain).

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule to redirect every URI that is not `/magic` or `/magic/` to a sub-domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect /magic
RewriteRule ^magic/?$ / [L,NC,R=301]

# redirect anything except /magic
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(magic/?)?$ https://sub.example.com [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about the URL with ```/magic```, it will open like a directory (```example.com/magic```), right ? I want ```example.com/magic``` to open the main domain ```example.com``` not as a directory, is that possible using .htaccess ?

Comment: I tried your updated answer but it is still opening as a directory ```example.com/magic``` and not as ```example.com``` :(

Comment: Thank you @Anubhava, but it's not working, is there a way to stop if first rule went through successfully ? Kind of if else statement if possible ?? As it is not finding a breakpoint and hence going ahead to the subdomain. :(

Comment: Try my updated rule again after completely clearing your browser cache.